# Looking for techniques of How to measure the Similarity/Dissimilarity between two images?

Tags: reference-request, similarity, image-processing

I would like to compute the similarity/dissimilarity between two images *L* and *R*.

I know one way which is : computing the histogram of blocks of each image, and then using Bhattacharyya measure I asset if the blocs are similar or not. The histogram are normalized the result are between 0 and 1. The reference to this is on this article :

> Bhattacharyya, A., “On a measure of divergence between two statistical
>   populations defined by their probability distribution,” Bulletin of
>   the Calcutta Mathematical Society 35, 99–110 (1943).

Well, I know that there is other measures (MI, Tanimoto, etc) and I would like to know if there is other ways to compute the Similarity/Dissimilarity between two images. I mean using histograms , it is kind of region based similarity measure, but is there some pixels related similarity techniques or more region based ones ?

### Update 1

To illustrate what I want, here is an example of two images to be compared. As you can see it is related to medical imaging (here there is two parts of the brain but I am talking about a more general case) :

[image]

[image]

If only I can get a MAP of simmilarity/dissimilarity between those two images. The technique I proposed above works fine , but i am requesting some references for other similar techniques.

Comment: You might look at the [SSIM: Structural Similarity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_similarity) measure.

Comment: The effectiveness of the measure would depend on the kind of image you are dealing with. You could be comparing human faces, or satellite imagery etc. It is not entirely mathematical.

Comment: @RajeshD is right. *Similarity* with respect to what?

Comment: @RajeshD I  Forget to mention that it is related to medical imaging.

Comment: @WłodzimierzHolsztyński with respect to what for example ? My question is kind of general I will improve it

Comment: Have you tried the "measure of similarity of images" googling? The search brings 426000000 pages.

Comment: Of course. That's why I am asking here ...

Comment: Opened a meta thread to discuss this question being constituted as mathematics. http://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/2303/14414

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One particular application to medical scans, that may be relevant for your problem, is the alignment and fusion of information in images of the same tissue obtained by different methods (MRI, CT, ultrasound). This application goes by the name of [image registration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_registration), and it has a very extensive literature, with a variety of [software tools](http://www.cbica.upenn.edu/sbia/software/dramms/) that you can download.

- The *mathematical* connections are explored in [￼Mathematics
  Meets Medicine: An Optimal Alignment.](https://www.siam.org/meetings/op08/Modersitzki.pdf) See also this more general review: 
  [Mathematical Methods In Medical Image Processing.](http://www.math.wisc.edu/~angenent/preprints/medicalBAMS.pdf)
- Here is a [comparison](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/inserm-00879579/document)
  of 8 different similarity measures that have been tested in this
  context:

> In this paper, eight intensity-based similarity measures for CT and
>   ultrasound scans are evaluated. Six of these use the information from
>   the histogram of images while two of them use the spatial information
>   and intensity values. They are: mutual information, normalized mutual
>   information, entropy correlation coefficient, joint entropy, point
>   similarity measure based on mutual information, histogram energy,
>   correlation ratio, and Woods criterion. Each intensity-based
>   similarity measure was assessed for its capability to align and fuse
>   complementary information in CT and ultrasound images. We compared its
>   accuracy, capture range, distinctiveness of the optimum, risk and
>   non-convergence, and number of minima.

- You can find algorithms for some of these similarity measures in a [Matlab toolbox.](https://sites.google.com/site/myronenko/research/mirt)

Answer (score 0):

A quite naive method would be to create an image, where each pixel-value equals the "distance" between the corresponding pixels of the source images, i.e. $r(x,y) := \vert p(x,y)-q(x,y)\vert$ and check the size of the compressed "difference image".
The smaller the size of the compressed difference-image, the closer are the source images.

That approach can however not unveil semantic similarity; but as it is fairly simple to implement, it should be a good start.
One could different kinds of compression (e.g. lossy and lossless) and pick the most suitable one. Simply storing the difference image in various image-file formats might already suffice.

**Edit**

seeing the medical application of similarity detection, I can imagine that the true underlying use case actually is a *classification* or, *recognition* problem.
There are other problems, that seem to be of similar nature:

- **Face Recognition** and **Optical Character Recognition**; those are commonly solved successfully with [Neural Networks](http://clgiles.ist.psu.edu/papers/IEEE.TNN.face.recognition.hybrid.nn.pdf).
- **Morphological Similarity**; there a classical method is the [Thompson Transform](http://www-history.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/Miscellaneous/darcy.html) first presented in Thompson's *On Growth and Form*

I found Ardeshir Goshtasby's chapter about [Similarity and Dissimilarity Measures](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-1-4471-2458-0_2#page-1)  quite useful.

Comment: Interesting, but it is the most obvious method. In my case it won't "really" work. Because the registration is not 100% good .... But it is another way to check dissimilarity. Thank you for your contribution.

Comment: @OSryx without having concrete examples of pictures that should be classified similar or dissimilar and without any hint about the background of your question, it will be hard to suggest something more elaborate. The only other generic method I can think of, would be to train a neural network.

Comment: I see, I **updated** my question with two pictures that show two blocks of a medical image (normal brain). I would like to compare them. I hope I am more clear now, please feel free to ask more questions so that I make my question more "good". How can we use NN to compare two images please ?

Comment: can you add the NN similarity technique to your answer ... please

Comment: @OSryx I just added two new ideas to my answer; Please note, that I have no expertise in either of the methods, but maybe some other MO user can jump in. I merely wanted to open new views on your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried G-H similarity measure? Check this paper:
http://sites.fas.harvard.edu/~cs277/papers/gromov.pdf
Memoli 2007